# Apply favorite tags in all question lists

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Why favorite and ignore tags in "featured", "hot", "week", "month" tabs has behavior another than on "interesting" tab?

Questions with ignored tags just disappears on "interesting" tab of questions, and on "hot" tab they just shading.

I think it will be useful to create "interesting featured", "interesting hot" tabs, or have possibility remove ignored questions from featured and hot question lists.

Comment: Can't see any difference for favorite, just ignored tags being shaded instead of hidden. Care you explain what's the difference for favorite tags?

Comment: The difference is " just ignored tags being shaded instead of hidden" :) This mean you have to scroll all stuff that are not interesting for you

Comment: Something like hashtag?